# TypeScriptでアクセストークンを外部ファイル（token.ts）に記述してimportして読み込めるようにしたい。

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

Next.jsでブログを作成しているものです。Githubのパーソナルアクセストークンをコードにそのまま記述するとGithubにコードをあげる際に困るので、載せたくないアクセストークンを外部ファイルに記述してそれを `.gitignore`で無視しようと思うのですが上手く行きません。

#### やった事

- next.jsのルートフォルダに`token.ts`を作成して`const accessToken = "アクセストークン";`
- これを読み込みたいファイルで`import accessToken from '../token'`であとは好きな所で `accessToken` すれば使えると思ったのですが赤い~~が出てエラーになります。

#### エラーの内容

トークンが書かれたtoken.ts側のエラー

```
'token.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module
```

読み込み側のエラー

```
File '/Users/username/Desktop/mac_work/nodejs/blog/my-blog/token.ts' is not a module.
```

Comment: token.jsモジュールから `accessToken` 変数をエクスポートしていますか？

Comment: はい、そうしたいです。

Comment: tsをjsに変更したらトークンファイル側のエラーは消えたのですが、読み込みは出来ていないみたいです。

Answer (score 0):

**読み込みたいファイルtoken.ts**

```
//exportと忘れていた。
export const accessToken = "token";
```

**読み込みたいファイル側で**

```
// {}で囲むのを忘れていた。
import { accessToken } from '../token'
```